# Ошибки при запуске скрипта на сервере

Tags: python, linux, база-данных, sql-server, pandas

Есть скрипт untitled0.py:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pandas as pd

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.000.00.00;DATABASE=db;UID=login;PWD=pass")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
qry = """select * from sales"""
sales_temp = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
sales_temp.to_csv('sales.csv', sep =';', index = False)
```

При запуске этого скрипта следующая ошибка:

```
    [login@aa-bbbb f]$ python3 untitled0.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled0.py", line 16, in <module>
    sales_temp = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 438, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1218, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1087, in execute
    return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2190, in execute
    connection = self._contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2251, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2289, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1555, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2285, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 773, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 139, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 657, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 69, in __exit__
    exc_value, with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 652, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 490, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/dbapi)
```

Как исправить ситуацию? Ничего толкового сам не нашел.

Comment: Что такое 192.000.00.00?

Comment: @hedgehogues, считайте, что ip сервера

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534154/linux-python3-cant-open-lib-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7

Помогла доустановка элементов, приведенных в ссылке

Answer (score 2):

Под Linux лучше использовать связку [`pymssql` + `sqlalchemy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pymssql):

> pymssql is a Python module that provides a Python DBAPI interface
>   around FreeTDS.
>
> **Modern versions of this driver worked very well with SQL Server and
>   FreeTDS from Linux and were highly recommended**. However, pymssql is
>   currently unmaintained and has fallen behind the progress of the
>   Microsoft ODBC driver in its support for newer features of SQL Server.
>   The latest official release of pymssql at the time of this document is
>   version 2.1.4 (August, 2018) and it lacks support for:
>
> - table-valued parameters (TVPs),
> - datetimeoffset columns using timezone-aware datetime objects (values are sent and retrieved as strings), and
> - encrypted connections (e.g., to Azure SQL), when pymssql is installed from the pre-built wheels. Support for encrypted connections
>     requires building pymssql from source, which can be a nuisance,
>     especially under Windows.
>
> The above features are all supported by mssql+pyodbc when using
>   Microsoft’s ODBC Driver for SQL Server (msodbcsql), which is now
>   available for Windows, (several flavors of) Linux, and macOS.

```
import pandas as pd                       #  pip install pandas
import pymssql                            #  pip install pymssql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine      #  pip install sqlalchemy

# pymssql
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@hostname:port/dbname')

...

sales_temp = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
```